# In Gamemaker standard v1.4, is it possible to create Bridge Builder physics and joints in 2D?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-1.4

I'm trying to create a 2D physics game, where there are structures that are held by breakable joints (that can be broken from compression or tension) that work similarly to the 2001 indie game, Bridge Builder. Is this type of physics possible in Gamemaker?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. GMS1.4 (and GMS2 as well) contains Box2D implementation. 
For details please check the manual - physic world section.